# input function doesn't work when i use it inside of print function?

Tags: python, if-statement, input, printing

I mean I can't use it this way

```
if order == 'pizza':
        print(input('pizza price is ' + pizza + 'Ok?'))
```

Why I'm using the input inside the print function is to give an answer and question at the same time that why I said `pizza price is ___ + ok?`

it's not working for me. is that mean there is a better way to do it. I mean printing an input. I have this code to simulate a Food order app.

How to make this work

```
pizza = 5
Burger = 2
kbab = 2
price = 10
total = price

order = input('what is your order: ')

if order == 'pizza':
    print(input('pizza price is ' + pizza + 'Ok?'))
```

Comment: What? This is an extremely confusing prompt. Please elaborate and specify what you're asking for...

Comment: @12944qwerty ignore everything except the code Why its not working

Comment: That shouldn't be how questions work. We won't assume what's going wrong in a code. You need to give us the details and clarify the issue

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all you need to have the numbers as strings, not integers. Next just remove the print statement and leave the input statement alone. So you should end up with something like this:

```
pizza = '5'
Burger = '2'
kbab = '2'
price = '10'
total = price

order = input('what is your order: ')

if order == 'pizza':
    input('pizza price is ' + pizza + ' Ok?')
```

Comment: Oh okay I'll do that next time

Comment: @BuddyBob I'm sorry for the question I edited it . is that ok for now

Comment: but what's the question?

Comment: @BuddyBob I'm very sorry I'm new here and really don't know how o make a good question with good details and info i didn't understand the How to make a good question page but I edited the question again now please check it

Comment: No, problem. I'm here to help. Btw, the answer above will show you how it is done. Look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @BuddyBob Hey is the question better Now . I edited I think it should be public no more closed Right?